# Xamarin.Ios , read all incoming notifications, without user interaction

Tags: ios, notifications, background, xamarin.ios

Is there any way to read notifications from all IOS apps (e.g., whatsapp, facebook) without the user clicking on the notification? And the application runs in the background. The idea is I want to make an application that takes all the notifications I've got on the iphone to send them to a server so then I can see them on another gadget.
The methods `DidReceiveRemoteNotification` and `ReceivedLocalNotification` works only if the user tap the notification.

Comment: It is not possible.

Comment: It is possible, but is not so easy. The only way to take IOS notifications is over bluetooth low energy. You have to subscribe to ANCS(Apple notification central service https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Introduction/Introduction.html) service, with an client applcation(client - notification consumer, server - notification producer must be paired). Example for Windows client: https://github.com/troufster/AncsNotifier . Example for Mac client: https://github.com/indragiek/INDANCSClient